# Why is getTime() returning inconsistent values?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to use `getTime()` function to calculate the date difference. As per my understanding, the latest date would return higher `getTime()` value compared to earlier date?

```
function libraryFine(d1, m1, y1, d2, m2, y2) {
    let returnDate = new Date();
    returnDate.setDate(d1);
    returnDate.setMonth(m1);
    returnDate.setYear(y1); 

    let dueDate = new Date();
    dueDate.setDate(d2);
    dueDate.setMonth(m2);
    dueDate.setYear(y2); 

    let datediff = returnDate.getTime() - dueDate.getTime();
    console.log(returnDate.getTime());
    console.log(dueDate.getTime());
    console.log(datediff);
}
```

But the function above logs inconsistent values for following two sets -

`d1=31, m1=5, y1=2014, d2=1, m2=5, y2=2014` returns -ve for `datediff`, shouldn't that be positive?
`d1=9, m1=6, y1=2015, d2=6, m2=6, y2=2015` returns +ve for `datediff`, seems fine?

Where is the miss?

Comment: try setting the year, then the month then the date ... since June 31 isn't valid (your first date) - actually, you should be doing `new Date(y, m, d)` rather than what you're doing, because of things like months having different number of days in it

Comment: Isn't that May?

Comment: No, 5 is June ... 0 is January .... etc

Comment: I see. Thanks a bunch mate. Just wonder though, as how does setting year first helps handle the issue?

Comment: well ... don't do that either - but it will have less overflows - but the proper way is `new Date(y, m, d)` then you'll be fine - if you want to pass in months as 1-based, then it's `new Date(y, m-1, d)` - read [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) - it's worth it

Comment: I did that only `let returnDate = new Date(y1, m1, d1);    let dueDate = new Date(y2, m2, d2);`, but why does it return different values for `console.log(returnDate.getMonth()); console.log(dueDate.getMonth());` , returns 6 and 5 respectively for first input.

Comment: because of OVERFLOW ... read the documentation, it will explain what happens if you set the date > number of days in the month

Comment: I see what you mean now. Sure, I am onto the documentation friend. Thanks a bunch!!